# Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to learn WPF. I am following along with a book(WPF in 24 hours) and occasionally I get the following error:

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory has been corrupted.

When I click "OK" the application continues to run as if nothing is wrong.So far I have worked with XAML only and have not entered any other code. The examples that I have found so far in SO and google reference specific code issues. Any shove in the right direction would be appreciated.

Oh...I am using VS2008 Pro

Comment: what OS? Using source control at all?

Comment: Happens to me too. I think this is a Visual Studo bug. Restarting the Visual Studio works.

Comment: The OS is Vista Home Premium. I am not using source control in this case as they are simply samples from the book. I do have subvserion setup though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this when declaring a Style without specifying the TargetType. I cannot remember if that was in WPF or Silverlight2 though.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but in case it helps someone...
I had this error as a build error in a XAML file of a Template10, MVVM UWP app.
The reason appears to be because I was referencing a ViewModel that is in a separate .dll.
Moved the referenced ViewModel into the app, the build error goes away.